# Magento doesn't detect child theme in different store view

Tags: theme, store-view, parent-child-theme

I have a Magento website with one store view (ITALIAN) and a theme with the child theme and everything is working good.
Today I created a second store view (ENGLISH) but this doesn't recognize the child theme, but only the default theme.

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must go into `System -> Configuration -> Design`. Then choose the english store view in top left. Uncheck the `use website` and insert your `package` and `theme` details as you did for the Italian store view. Clear the cache.

Comment: This is a screenshot of the current configuration http://tinypic.com/r/25qevyw/8

Comment: The theme is "neighborhood" and it works well, but in the english store view it didn't recognize the child theme.

Comment: So both store views belong to the same website, both have the same theme configuration, but the theme in the english store doesn't show. Some ideas: 1) Check in `System -> Design` that nothing is overwritting the `System -> Configuration -> Design`. 2) Insert the theme details at store level for the Italian store view (uncheck the use website and insert them there). 3) Make sure that the english store is really run: reindex and visit categories that should be only shown in the english store view.

Comment: Cool! It was is System -> Design where I didn't create a custom design for english! Many thanks :)